# Rename file in PHPStorm without refactoring

Tags: php, file, rename, phpstorm

How do I quickly rename a file name **without refactoring** in PHPStorm? Even after I've just created the file, PHPStorm takes a long time to search through my files for its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also an option available Right-click on file select "Show In Explorer" and then in windows explorer rename file by F2. It will not refactor or effect any other file in your project.

Comment: This is eventually the fastest way when you are confident that you just want to rename and your renaming will not break the code.

Answer (score 30):

My technique for renaming files quickly is to single-click the file name and press **Shift-F6**. A dialog opens and you can immediately type the new name of the file and hit return/enter to complete the rename.

I find this technique intuitive because you **don't** have to move your mouse to the dialog window, type the new name, or click anything to confirm. As long as all you're doing is a rename that you know is safe, you just type it and go.

I also like this feature because you still have the option of quickly previewing the changes before they're made. And on those occasions when you are refactoring something with possible implications to the rest of your app, you can still enable "Search for references" and/or "Search in comments and strings" to get the whole enchilada. (I have those options disabled by default.)

I agree with you that right-clicking the file name, scrolling down to Refactor, selecting Rename, and then entering the new name is cumbersome, especially if the safe checks are enabled. I find that PhpStorm developers seem to understand these types of issues and usually have thought of a "faster way" to do things as well.

Comment: You can also use mnemonics(Alt + <underlined_letter>) to quickly enable/disable checkboxes.

Answer (score 11):

You can't do it without refactoring, though `Refactor` | `Rename` is usually very quick and you can disable options to search for references.

Comment: sometimes I create a new file and then i want change it's name. Although the file just is created the refactorer report a lot of refrences to it?!

Comment: False references can be found if you search for them in comments and the name of file is some common word, so just disable both checkboxes in the Rename dialog.

Answer (score 6):

Default is **Shift-F6**. For not refactoring, disable the checkboxes in the popup.

I wanted to use **F2** for file renaming like Windows default.

You can make a shortcut for **F2**. Go to:

1. File
2. Settings
3. Keymap
4. Search for "rename"
5. Doubleclick "Refactor -> Rename"
6. Click "Keyboard Shortcut"
7. Press F2
8. Ok

**EDIT**

If it does not work immediately, restart PHPStorm.

Comment: +1 This is why I came here. Google brought me, and disappointed I am not. F2 is for me the expected shortcut. Who ever heard of Shift+f6 for rename operations?

Comment: Weird, not sure why this shortcut needs a restart, while others don't.

Comment: I did all of this but forgot to restart phpstorm .. :(

Answer (score 1):

This will work for linux users.

It depends on `zenity`, so first check if it installed on your system,
run in console:  `zenity --version`
If it output something like `3.18.1.1` - then it's ok.

Create file `idea-rename.sh` with content below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FileDir="$1"
FileName="$2"

NewFileName="$(zenity --entry --title "Rename ${FileName}" --text "Please enter new name" --entry-text "${FileName}" --ok-label="Rename" 2>/dev/null)"

if [[ "${NewFileName}" != "" ]]; then
    if [[ -f "${FileDir}/${FileName}" ]]; then
        path="${FileDir}"
        name="${NewFileName}"

        if [[ "${NewFileName}" == *"/"* ]]; then
            IFS='/' read -ra newDirs <<< "$NewFileName"
            IFS='/' read -ra dirs <<< "$FileDir"

            last=$((${#newDirs[@]} - 1))
            path=""
            name="${newDirs[$last]}"
            unset 'newDirs[last]'

            if [[ "${NewFileName}" == *"./"* ]]; then
                for i in "${!newDirs[@]}"; do
                    dir="${newDirs[i]}"

                    if [[ "$dir" == ".." ]]; then
                        unset 'newDirs[i]'
                        j=$i

                        while [ $j -ge 0 ]; do
                            j=$(($j-1))

                            if [ $j -lt 0 ]; then
                                for (( k=${#dirs[@]}-1 ; k>=0 ; k-- )); do
                                    if [[ "${dirs[k]}" ]]; then
                                        echo 'dirs[k]'
                                        unset 'dirs[k]'
                                        break
                                    fi
                                done
                            elif [[ "${newDirs[j]}" ]]; then
                                echo 'newDirs[j]'
                                unset 'newDirs[j]'
                                break
                            fi
                        done

                    elif [[ "$dir" == "." ]]; then
                        unset 'newDirs[i]'
                    fi
                done
            fi

            for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
                if [[ "$dir" ]]; then
                    path="${path}/${dir}"

                    if [[ ! -d "$path" ]]; then
                        mkdir -m 0777 "$path"
                    fi
                fi
            done

            for dir in "${newDirs[@]}"; do
                if [[ "$dir" ]]; then
                    path="${path}/${dir}"

                    if [[ ! -d "$path" ]]; then
                        mkdir -m 0777 "$path"
                    fi
                fi
            done
        fi

        if [[ ! -f "${FileDir}/${NewFileName}" ]]; then
            mv "${FileDir}/${FileName}" "${path}/${name}"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Open your `Settings` > `Tools` > `External Tools`, click on [image: add button]
and fill form as below

[image: Adding tool]

Name: `Rename`
Group: `File`
Program: `/bin/bash`
Parameters: `/path/to/idea-rename.sh $FileDir$ $FileName$`
Working Directory: `$ProjectFileDir$`

Click `Ok`, `Apply`
After that you can see new item in your file menu

[image: Menu]

When you click on `rename` will opens dialog

[image: Rename dialog]

After rename in some cases phpstorm not sync files, so in path where located your file need to click in file menu "Synchronize 'path'"

[image: Synchronize path menu]