# Rename file in PhpStorm without refactoring?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

Firstly, I have already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817291/rename-file-in-phpstorm-without-refactoring) and using the **Shift+F6** method is just a quicker way to bring up the standard refactor option.

I am using PhpStorm 2018.1

Perhaps this is a bug in the latest version as I don't recall having issues with this before, but whenever I use the refactor method and *don't* select any of the display checkboxes as below:

[image]

When I click the *refactor* button it still seems to refactor it as it initially freezes for a few seconds and then comes up with this:

[image]

Firstly, I'm pretty sure older versions never used to do this unless you checked one of the checkboxes (didn't there used to be two?) and secondly, even when you *were* refactoring something I don't recall it freezing up, it would come straight up with the progress bar search window.

Comment: Hmm, weird, I've got an extra checkbox labeled "Search for references" above yours, but I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, PhpStorm 2018.1 (same as your version). Also, it doesn't freeze when I click _refactor_, just runs instantly. [Screenshot of my popup.](https://imgur.com/rS4zxXx)

Comment: @Davіd Hmmmmmm weird. That's what I thought, that there was another checkbox there; however, it's not just my installation as I have observed this behavior on both my home copy and the copy I use at work, which is 2018.1 as well, but only a different OS. Windows 7 at home and Windows 10 at work.

Comment: On windows 7 that works as it used to, showing one more checkbok. The behavior of that dialog seems to change depending on the selected file. If you select a class file or a text file is the dialog different. If you create a different kind of project does that dialog change?

Comment: @IliePandia Hmmmm...... I checked with other files types and you're right, I do see more/different checkboxes for them, however no matter what type of PHP file it is it doesn't seem to matter, only shows the one checkbox as above; which doesn't explain why David sees two.

Comment: @IliePandia I have just noticed I see another checkbox display for PHP files, "Rename class", but only when the class name matches the filename of the file.

Comment: If possible try to reset your Phpstorm install and change the theme too... that may do it...

Comment: @IliePandia What do you mean by "reset"? I tried a different theme but no change. Also, as stated, this also happens on the copy I have at work, albeit I did import my settings from my home copy to that one.

Comment: Reset: uninstall, remove settings, plugins, cache and history.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a plugin, specifically the [Yii2 Support](https://github.com/nvlad/yii2support) plugin; when that is disabled, the checkboxes show as per normal.